# Errors in using integral2 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I have asked this question two days ago. Now I re-derive the formulas and write new codes. But I still encounter the same error in using integral2.

```
clear
clc
% parameter settings
syms KI c r phi
KId = 0.000005;
G = 76.0;
nu = 0.31;
Vh = 2;
NA = 6.02214129*10^23;
b = 3.52*sqrt(6)/6;
A0 = G*b^2*(2-nu)/(8*pi*(1-nu));
lambda = 2;
m = 2.2;
kapa = 1.0;
beff = b;
delta2 = 1.0;
D = 1.9*10^(-14);
kB = 1.38064852*10^(-23);
R = 8.3144598;
E = 250;
Rc = 2*b;
for c0=0.0000005:0.0000005:0.0001
    for T=1:1:300
        for rou=b:b:10*b
            for theta=0:0.01*pi:pi
                h = (5*(1+nu)*D*Vh*cos(theta/2)*KI^2/(12*sqrt(2*pi)*kB*NA*T*KId))^(2/5);
                B0 = G*Vh*c*h^2/(2*pi*(1-nu));
                sigma1122 = ((cos(2*theta)*rou^2 + cos(2*phi)*r^2 - cos(theta - phi)*2*rou*r)*((sqrt(rou/r) + sqrt(r/rou))*cos((theta + phi)/2) - 2) + (sin(2*theta)*rou^2 - sin(2*phi)*r^2 - sin(theta - phi)*2*rou*r)*(sqrt(rou/r) - sqrt(r/rou))*sin((theta + phi)/2))*B0/((cos(2*theta)*rou^2 + cos(2*phi)*r^2 - cos(theta - phi)*2*rou*r)^2 + (sin(2*theta)*rou^2 - sin(2*phi)*r^2 - sin(theta - phi)*2*rou*r)^2); % 2*(psiHc+conj(psiHc));
                sigma12 = KI*sin(theta)*cos(theta/2)/(2*sqrt(2*pi*rou));
                c = c0*exp(((1+nu)*sigma1122/3-2*E*Vh*(c-c0)/(9*(1-nu)))*Vh/(R*T));
                fun = @(r,phi) c*sin(2*phi)/r;
                eq = pi*rou*A0*(log(8*rou*m/(lambda*b))-2)+kapa*G*beff^2*delta2-0.5*b*pi*rou^2*(sigma12-(G*Vh/(2*pi*(1-nu)*NA))*integral2(fun,0,Rc,0,2*pi));
                solve(eq==0,KI);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The error information is:

> Warning: The system is inconsistent. Solution does not exist.
>
> In symengine (line 57)
>
> In sym/privBinaryOp (line 903)
>
> In  /  (line 297)
>
> In @(r,phi)c*sin(2*phi)/r
>
> In integral2Calc>integral2t/tensor (line 228)
>
> In integral2Calc>integral2t (line 55)
>
> In integral2Calc (line 9)
>
> In integral2 (line 106)
>
> In KIpredictor (line 44)
>
> Error using integral2Calc>integral2t/tensor (line 231)
>
> Input function must return 'double' or 'single' values. Found 'sym'.
>
> Error in integral2Calc>integral2t (line 55)
>
> [Qsub,esub] = tensor(thetaL,thetaR,phiB,phiT);
>
> Error in integral2Calc (line 9)

```
> [q,errbnd] = integral2t(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,optionstruct);
```

> Error in integral2 (line 106)

```
> Q = integral2Calc(fun,xmin,xmax,yminfun,ymaxfun,opstruct);
```

> Error in KIpredictor (line 44)

```
            > eq =
            pi*rou*A0*(log(8*rou*m/(lambda*b))-2)+kapa*G*beff^2*delta2-0.5*b*pi*rou^2*(sigma12-(G*Vh/(2*pi*(1-nu)*NA))*integral2(fun,0,Rc,0,2*pi));
```

I think the problem is due the complexity of the integrand. A detailed description of the integand is in the attached figure.
[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIqu8.png)

Comment: Some notes/complications I see: (1) `c` is defined by `c` both in the code and the equations; this will create quite a non-trivial integral equation and associated solution method.  (2) I'm wondering why you're using the numerical `integral2` versus a doubly nested symbolic `int` since you're using Symbolic math. (3) Looking at the `1/r` term in you integrals, I'm wondering if you forgot the `r^2*sin(theta)` Jacobian multiplier for spherical integration.

Comment: Hi Troy, thanks for your comments. (1) As shown in the attached figure, c cannot be expressed explicitly. This may be the cause of the errors. (2) I am very new in MATLAB, I do not know if there are some other commands can do this double integral. (3) I've wrote the integrals rightly, following the formulas in the attachment.

Comment: (1) Then you have quite a complicated integral equation with `c` parametrized by `KI`, which I unfortunately don't have experience with. (2) Switching to `fun = c*sin(2*phi)/r;` and `int(int(fun,phi,0,2*pi),r,0,Rc)` allows the creation of `eq` without error. (3) If the integral is correct, I'd be very afraid that the `1/r` term in `fun` may result in an undefined value since it diverges at zero.

Comment: Yes, the singularity caused by '1/r' term is really a big problem, which has been mentioned in some textbooks. However, I have not found any numerical implementations for this kind of question. And now the error is: Cannot find explicit solution.